# Finite cover of balls for a bounded subset

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Suppose X is a bounded subset of a k-dimensional manifold $M$ $\subset$ $R^n$ with $(k-1)$-dimensional volume $0$. I need to show that this implies for all $d>0$, all points of X can be contained in finitely many balls (assume p of them) with respective radii $r_i$ such that:

$\sum_{i=1}^p {r_i}^{k-1}<d$

I can see how to contain them in a finite number of balls, but the radius with the power of k-1 is proving difficult to see.